# swift3 call alert function from other swift.file

Tags: ios, swift3

I am new of swift3. Now, I am finding a way to call alert function from other swift.file

Like this:

```
//MainView.swift
//Call function
AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "Title", message: "message..." )

//Another page for storing functions
//Function.swift

public class AlertFun {
    class func ShowAlert(title: String, message: String ) {    
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: tile, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Problem in here...Cannot do this in this way....

```
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How can I implement it? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show an alert from another class in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015171/how-to-show-an-alert-from-another-class-in-swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the viewController reference as a parameter to the showAlert function like:

```
//MainView.swift
//Call function
AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "Title", message: "message...", in: self)

//Another page for storing functions
//Function.swift

public class AlertFun {
    class func ShowAlert(title: String, message: String, in vc: UIViewController) {    
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: tile, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well tested. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Call Method for your controller**

```
Utility.showAlertOnViewController(targetVC: self, title: "", message:"")
```

**Your Class**

```
class Utility: NSObject {
    class func showAlertOnViewController(
            targetVC: UIViewController,
            title: String,
                message: String)
        {

            let alert = UIAlertController(
                title: title,
                message: message,
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let okButton = UIAlertAction(
                title:"OK",
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
                handler:
                {
                    (alert: UIAlertAction!)  in
            })
            alert.addAction(okButton)
            targetVC.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that none of the examples I've seen will work without getting the warning:

> Attempt to present `<UIAlertController: 0x7f82d8825400>` on `<app name>` whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

The code that works for me is as follows. The function call is as before:

```
 AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "Title", message: "message...", in: self)
```

However, to make this work, the `Function.swift` file has to display the alert inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async`. So the `Function.swift` file should look like this:

```swift
public class AlertFun
{
    class func ShowAlert(title: String, message: String, in vc: UIViewController)
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```