# How do you show an alert in every view controller when the app is active (foreground)?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to show an alert when the user opens the app (app became active). The reason for showing the alert is to give information that the user is logged in, on another device, so they will be logged out from the device.

The following code is implemented in `AppDelegate`. My expectation is - if it's going to cause failure - it means they will be logged out.

The API works well, but I don't know how to show the alert when the app's in the foreground. How do you implement this correctly?

I don't want to hit the API in every `viewDidLoad` in each `viewController`.

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        guard let fcmToken = fcmToken else { return }
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
        
        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)

         is generated.
        guard !AuthManager.shared.userLoginSession.isEmpty,  //true  user belom login
              let tokenlogin = SettingsManager.tokenlogin,
              !tokenlogin.isEmpty //true  token login harus kosong
        else { return }
        NetworkManager.instance.requestObject(ServiceAPI.start(regID: fcmToken, id: AuthManager.shared.userLoginSession, token: tokenlogin), c: SingleResponse<StartResponse>.self) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                AuthManager.shared.userLoginSession = response.data.apikey ?? ""
                //                MoEngage.sharedInstance().setAlias("1234")
            case .failure(let error):
                // If it's going failure. it means they will be logged out 
                print("FCM with error", error.description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I answered something similar a couple of years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40016326/5927585). Feel free to take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add code in AppDelegate below like this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:   [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
   
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
        let window = UIApplication.shared
            .connectedScenes
            .flatMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows ?? [] }
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Test Data", message:"Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                
        // add an action (button)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
               
        
        window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true)

    }
    
    return true
}
```

Comment: Hello Dhruvin, thanks for answering. correct me if i'm wrong. From what i see, the code means to run after `1 second` .  I wanna make sure if it's a good idea or not. 

From my source code (wait for fcm) and then set userdefault variable. After that  i check the userdefault value in alertcontroller module . Is it always going to be good in 1 second ?

Comment: As per my knowledge there is no issue with delay, its good to add, bcz some time when app launch there is some chance that we have to wait for rootViewController to present alert. Also you can reduce time, I put over there bcz I have added code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I think in your case it might be no need to add delay. But for safer side you can add slight delay.